# Consulta ao banco de dados usando ORDER BY mata minha busca

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, php-7

meu codigo exibe uma lista de pessoas e um campo de busca no topo.
tudo funciona normal, inclusive a busca.
mas eu preciso que as pessoas apareçam de maneira aleatória. O problema é que quando eu uso o ORDER BY rand() (ou qualquer outro ORDER BY) minha busca para de funcionar. ao fazer a busca aparece o erro atribuido ao $resultado.

```
<?php require_once("conecta.php"); ?>

<?php
//consulta dos dados

$assistentes = "SELECT * FROM assistentes ORDER BY rand() ";


if(isset($_GET["buscauser"])){
    $nomebusca = $_GET["buscauser"];
    $assistentes .= " WHERE nome LIKE '%{$nomebusca}%' OR sobrenome LIKE '%{$nomebusca}%' OR cidade LIKE '%{$nomebusca}%'  ";
}

$resultado = mysqli_query($conecta, $assistentes);
if (!$resultado){
    die('Falha na conexao com o banco');
}
?>
```

Comment: 'Falha na conexao com o banco' - atribuido a !$resultado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma sintaxe representativa da declaração SELECT é a seguinte:

```
 SELECT valores_a_exibir
     FROM nome_da_tabela
     WHERE expressão
     GROUP BY como_agrupar
     HAVING expressão
     ORDER BY como_ordenar
     LIMIT contagem_de_linhas;
```

Essa sintaxe é simplificada. A sintaxe completa do SELECT inclui clausulas adicionais. Todas as cláusulas que seguem a lista de colunas a serem exibidas são opcionais.

Por exemplo, você não precisa incluir uma cláusula LIMIT ao escrever uma declaração SELECT. Entretanto, quaisquer cláusulas que você incluir devem ser especificadas **na ordem mostrada**.

```
if(isset($_GET["buscauser"])){
    $nomebusca = $_GET["buscauser"];
    $assistentes = "SELECT * FROM assistentes WHERE nome LIKE '%{$nomebusca}%' OR sobrenome LIKE '%{$nomebusca}%' OR cidade LIKE '%{$nomebusca}%' ORDER BY rand()";
}else{
    $assistentes = "SELECT * FROM assistentes ORDER BY rand() ";
}
```

Comment: funciona. muito obrigado. agora preciso entender o porque funciona assim e não do meu jeito. de volta aos estudos! obrigado obrigado!

Comment: @TomZé, Editei a resposta explicando isso. Se resolveu seu problema marque a resposta como aceita, veja como em https://i.stack.imgur.com/evLUR.png.

Comment: perfeito. agora ficou claro. mais uma vez agradeço a atenção.